# How to execute a large list of Observables (web requests) in smaller batches?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a list of Observables that are each sending a web request to an API endpoint.

```
Observable<any>[] myWebRequests;
```

For now I execute them all at the same time:

```
combineLatest(myWebRequests).subscribe(result =>
    this.messageService.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: this.translateService.instant("StoryVersionEdit.PageTitle"),
        detail: this.translateService.instant("StoryVersionEdit.StoryVersionSaved"),
        closable: false
    }),
    error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

But when the list is large (e.g. 80 web requests), the API server gets flooded by all the requests at the same time and some end up in error.

I would like to batch this large list of requests and send them 10 at a time, wait for these to complete before sending the next 10.

How can I do that?

---

Edit 1: Here is how the myWebRequests is constructed:

```
...
Observable<any>[] myWebRequests = updateAllStoryVersionsBy(null, 'test', 'test', 'test');
...

updateAllStoryVersionsBy(
    assetHoldingNumber: string,
    assetHoldingLocation: string,
    originalValue_LegacyDataFormatSupport: string,
    originalValue_AssetHoldingEstablishment: string
): Observable<StoryVersion>[] {
    var storyVersionObservables: Observable<StoryVersion>[] = [];

    // Validations to only call the web server when relevant
    if (!this.storyVersion.assetHoldingNumber && !this.storyVersion.assetHoldingLocation)
        return storyVersionObservables;

    const changedProperties = this.getChangedProperties();

    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingNumber') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingLocation') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingEstablishment') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingRoom') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingNotes') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('recordingType') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('legacyItemHoldingType') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('legacyDataFormatSupport') < 0 &&
        changedProperties.indexOf('cbcVideoResolution') < 0
    )
        return storyVersionObservables;

    // Find story versions to update
    var allStoryVersionsToUpdate: Observable<IGuid[]>;
    if (assetHoldingNumber) {
        allStoryVersionsToUpdate = this.storyVersionService.findStoryVersionsByAssetHoldingNumber(assetHoldingNumber);
    }
    else if (assetHoldingLocation) {
        var queryParameters: StoryVersionGetByAssetHoldingRequest = {
            isUniqueOnly: false,
            assetHoldingLocation: assetHoldingLocation,
            assetHoldingEstablishment: originalValue_AssetHoldingEstablishment,
            legacyItemHoldingType: originalValue_LegacyDataFormatSupport,
            assetHoldingNumber: null,
            responsible: null,
            select: null,
            offset: 0,
            limit: 100
        };
        allStoryVersionsToUpdate = this.storyVersionService.findStoryVersionsByAssetHoldingLocation(queryParameters);
    }

    storyVersionObservables = <Observable<StoryVersion>[]><unknown>allStoryVersionsToUpdate
        .pipe(
            concatMap(data => {
                const items$ = data.map(g => {
                    var svToUpdate: any = {
                        guid: g.guid
                    };

                    // Only assign fields that were edited by the user

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingNumber') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.assetHoldingNumber = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.assetHoldingNumber;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingLocation') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.assetHoldingLocation = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.assetHoldingLocation;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingEstablishment') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.assetHoldingEstablishment = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.assetHoldingEstablishment;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingRoom') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.assetHoldingRoom = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.assetHoldingRoom;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('assetHoldingNotes') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.assetHoldingNotes = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.assetHoldingNotes;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('recordingType') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.recordingType = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.recordingType;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('legacyItemHoldingType') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.legacyItemHoldingType = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.legacyItemHoldingType;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('legacyDataFormatSupport') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.legacyDataFormatSupport = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.legacyDataFormatSupport;

                    if (changedProperties.indexOf('cbcVideoResolution') >= 0)
                        svToUpdate.cbcVideoResolution = this.storyVersionEditForm.value.cbcVideoResolution;

                    // The actual web request to fire for each!
                    return this.storyVersionService.updateStoryVersion(svToUpdate);
                });
                return forkJoin(...items$);
            }),
        )

    return storyVersionObservables;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) and provide the concurrency argument:

```js
from(myWebRequests).pipe(
    mergeMap(req$ => req$, 5) // <--- limit to 5 concurrent requests
).subscribe(
    result => this.messageService.add(...),
    error  => console.error(error)
);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, that looked promising! I tried it but looking at the network tab of my webapp, it seems that all requests are still fired in parallel (and some ending in error as before) with using this

Comment: Here's a sample of how it [should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74114000?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts).  Maybe try adding some logging to your calls to verify that the concurrency isn't working or maybe share some of your exact code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your follow-up, in fact I am pretty sure that your code is good and should work for my case...I am still new to RxJs so certainly there is something I must do incorrectly. I edited my question and added the big function that is building the array of web requests. The particularity is that first, a web request must be done to get a list of GUIDs, and then from this list of guids, the array of individual observables must be built. Is there anything wrong in that `updateAllStoryVersionsBy` function you think?

Comment: You are combining all your individual observables with `forkJoin`, which will execute them all at once.  Try removing the `forkJoin`.

Comment: Hi! I replaced `return forkJoin(...items$);` with `return items$;` but now in my network tab, no requests are fired at all from my large array of observables

Comment: Hi, I accepted your answer as it helped me a lot :) I am only missing one small piece now, maybe you have another good idea...my last question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128794/how-to-use-switchmap-to-subscribe-only-to-the-last-while-using-a-concurrent-par Thanks!