# How to use switchMap to subscribe only to the last, while using a concurrent parameter (only available in mergeMap)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74114000-n5t8dl?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts%3AL30

```
import './style.css';
import { of, from, mergeMap, delay, tap, defer, Observable, map, switchMap, combineLatest, } from 'rxjs';

GetIds()
  .pipe(mergeMap((x) => x.map((i) => fakeRequest(`#${i}`))))
  .pipe(mergeMap((req$) => req$, 3))
  .subscribe(
    (result) => console.log(`${result} DONE!`),
    (error) => console.error(error)
  );

function fakeRequest(label: string): Observable<string> {
  return defer(() =>
    of(label).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log(`> Fetching ${label}`)),
      delay(Math.random() * 5000 + 1250)
    )
  );
}

function GetIds(): Observable<number[]> {
  return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(tap((qi) => console.log(`> id ${qi}`)));
}
```

It's faking a couple web requests with a max of 3 concurrent using mergeMap.

Output:

```
> id 1,2,3,4,5
> Fetching #1
> Fetching #2
> Fetching #3
#2 DONE!
> Fetching #4
#1 DONE!
> Fetching #5
#4 DONE!
#5 DONE!
#3 DONE!
```

I am missing one thing: I would like the "DONE" message to appear **only at the end, once all the request are done**. Currently the "DONE" message is appearing after each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of emitting each result as they are received, you can emit an array of all results once the source completes using [`toArray`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/toArray):

```js
GetIds().pipe(
  mergeMap(x => getUpdateRequests(x)),
  mergeMap(req$ => req$, 3),
  toArray()
).subscribe(
  result => console.log(`${result} DONE!`),
  error => console.error(error)
);
```

Output:

```
> Fetching #444
> Fetching #1
> Fetching #2
> Fetching #3
> Fetching #4
> Fetching #5
#1,#2,#3,#444,#4,#5 DONE!
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74128794?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts)